# Strong vs Weak entities MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

For a assignment of MySQL/SQL, I need to create 2 different tables to show the *difference between strong entities and weak entities*.

Could someone show me an example of how I would do this?

I understand that a strong entity can exists without another entity, while the same is not true for a weak entity. So, for example, would a strong entity be as follows:

```
Employee(EmpNo, Name, EmpId)
```

?

But I am unsure how to create a table showing the differences.

Comment: Create a table of `Employee` table which will have a list of all *employees* and a `Managers` table. Now `Managers` table will have a foreign-key of `EmployeeID` thus Manager table will have a dependency on the `Employee` table and will make it a weak entity

Comment: could you clarify a little more clearly? so is this how it would be done?
Employee(employees)
Manages(Employeeid)

Comment: Yes...Logically it is ..As Managers table cant exist without Employee table... thus creating dependancy

Comment: Like i am still not able to comprehend this. how can managers not be able to exist when it isnt linked to employee in any way? do you think you could give me an example as my teacher did not clearly explain how you would implement this

Comment: I am answering your question please see my answer

Comment: sorry but i still dont understand, so to clarify would you have the employeeid entity in the employee table then?

Comment: Yes ufcrse, please look at my answer

Comment: Please see my answer and comment if you need more clarification

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted , if it has helped you .. so the other Users with the same issue can get help from this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the `Employee` table with the following columns  :

**`EmployeeID , EmpName, EmpDept,...`**

The `Managers` table would be like :

**`ManagerID, EmployeeID(foreign-key),ManagerName,...`**

Now , each **Manager is a Employee** , thus if at all there is a Manager in the `Manager` table , there would be the same entry in `Employee` table.

The ***"is a"*** relationship is maintained : `Each manager is a Employee but each Employee is not a Manager`

---

The query would be something like :

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
)

CREATE TABLE Managers
(
ManagerID int NOT NULL,
EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
..
...
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
)
```

Comment: Do you understand now  ?

Comment: I don't think there would be `primary key` for `Managers` here to represent it as weak entity!!

Comment: I removed it.. But i don't think why would that pose a problem ?

Comment: It will not pose any problem, but it won't be considered as `weak entity` then.

Comment: ohhkay ! Point noted!

Answer (score 3):

As you know Weak Entity is table which does not have a primary key **but the primary key of a weak entity set is formed by the primary key of the strong entity set on which the weak entity set is existence dependent,** plus the weak entity set’s discriminator.

[image: Relation between Strong and week entity]

The relationship between weak entity and strong entity set is called as Identifying Relationship. In example mentioned in above image, loan-payment is the identifying relationship for payment entity. A weak entity set is represented by doubly outlined box and corresponding identifying relation by a doubly outlined diamond as shown in figure. Here double lines indicate total participation of weak entity in strong entity set it means that every payment must be related via loan-payment to some account. The arrow from loan-payment to loan indicates that each payment is for a single loan. The discriminator of a weak entity set is underlined with dashed lines rather than solid line.

Let us consider another scenario, where we want to store the information of employees and their dependents. The every employee may have zero to n number of dependents. Every dependent has an id number and name.

Now let us consider the following data base:

There are three employees having E# as 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

> Employee having E# 1, has two dependents as 1, Rahat and 2, Chahat.
>
> Employee having E# 2, has no dependents.
>
> Employee having E# 3, has three dependents as 1, Raju; 2, Ruhi; 3
>   Raja.

Now, in case of Dependent entity id cannot act as primary key because it is not unique.

Thus, Dependent is a weak entity set having id as a discriminator. It has a total participation with the relationship "has" because no dependent can exist without the employees (the company is concerned with employees).

There are two tables need to created above e-r diagram. These are Employee having E# as single column which acts as primary key. The other table will be of Dependent having E#, id and name columns where primary key is the combination of (E# and id).

Comment: So for my example a strong entity would be

Comment: See, Strong Entity will have an `id` say in your example you have `employee` table with primary key say `emp num` which is a `strong entity`. As @AbhishekGosh said now if you have one more table say `Managers` without any `primary key` and that is considered as `weak entity` but it will be referring `emp num` of `employee`, as all the managers will be employees, and that will be considered as foreign key for `Managers` table.

Comment: Hope he gets now.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : Yea :)

Comment: ok now i think i understand what you are saying but how would i show the difference between Strong entities and weak entities with only 2 tables

Comment: There is nothing to show the difference. You need to explain why it is strong entity and why it is weak entity!! **The one with primary key is strong entity and one without primary key but referring other table's primary key, as foreign key is a weak entity**

Comment: @user3773272 : The tables will be self explanatory.. The rest explanation should be verbal I believe

Comment: Exactly!! I second that!! :)

Comment: In the `Dependant` table you add the `Managers` table and the entities i have explained you in the aswer

Comment: so would EmployeeID , EmpName be primary keys?

Comment: I meant to say would EmployeeID be a primary key?

Comment: Only `EmployeeID` is the primary key , as there can be Employees with the same name!

Comment: yea I just saw it, now i understand what he was talking about thank you so much for helping,and for your patience helping me through to understand it

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : It was a joint venture ! (Y)

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh.. Agree!! But answer has to be one.. :) and I found your's is the best with a proper example.. :) Nice work.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : Appreciated ! :)