# can a relationship between a weak entity set and a strong entity set be many-to-many?

Tags: database

Everywhere I've searched it's just saying that the relationship is *one-to-many* from *strong entity* to *weak entity*, but never exactly explained "why".

I mean, I don't understand why it can't be *many-to-many*. Those "many" entities from the *weak* entity set can map to "one" entity from the *strong* entity set, but "many" entities from *strong* entity set can also map to just "one" entity in the *weak* entity set (in my opinion); what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you going to add a key from the weak entity to the strong entity? That's why you can't have many `Strong` entities mapping to the `Weak` entity. In order to do so, the `Strong` entity would need the primary key of the `Weak` entity, but a `Weak` entity does not have its own primary key. A `Weak` entity is defined as an entity with primary keys made of other entities' primary keys. E.g.

[Strong vs Weak entities MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690902/strong-vs-weak-entities-mysql)

Also, see diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Just your one sentence about 'strong entity would need the primary key of the weak entity' cleared my confusion.